# if and comparing with ==

Tags: c++

I'm all newbie to programming, so please help me out. It seems that result variable doesn't have a correct value. I know it's better to use `cin` and `cout` but my tutor has asked me to use `printf` and `scanf`.

if I change the code to printf("%d", result); I wil get:
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'result' is being used without being initialized.
and if i change the code to scanf("%c", &c); %c will get white space from the first scanf()!!! so i have to write it this way scanf("%c%*c", &c); or this way scanf(" %c", &c);. it seems that %c in contrast to %d or %f does not skip white space.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main    ()
{
    int n1, n2;
    int result; 
    char c;
    printf("Lotfan addad aval ra vared konid\n");
    scanf("%d", &n1);
    printf("Lotfan addad Dovom ra vared konid\n");
    scanf("%d", &n2);
    printf("Please choose an operator\n");
    scanf("%c%*c", &c);
    if (c=='+')
    {
        result=n1+n2;
    }
    else if (c=='-')
    {
        result=n1-n2;
    }
    else if (c=='*')
    {
        result=n1*n2;
    }
    else if (c=='/')
    {
        result=n1/n2;
    }
    //else 
    //{
        //printf("error");
    //}
    //printf("%d%c%d=%d" ,n1,c,n2,&result);
    printf("%d", &result);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this C or C++?  Looking at your code, (other than the incorrect declaration of `main`) one would assume it is C.  Which language are you learning?  They are different.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I think the difference deosn't make any sense here.

Comment: your tutor's advice is bad, typesafe C++ streams are preferred.  If you must use `printf` though, add some for diagnostics of program flow and then take them out once it's working.  Or learn how to step thru the code in debugger (extra credit)

Comment: No, the difference here is not important to the question, but the learner has a tutor who is having him write C code instead of C++, and the student should be aware of that fact.

Comment: i'm suppose to learn c++ not c. but the problem is my tutor ages as much as master yoda!!!

Answer (score 4):

You don't always initialize `result`. If none of your `if` conditions evaluate to true, then it will be uninitialized. You'll need to make sure that you always initialize it.

What's more you must not pass `&result` to `printf` since that will print the address of `result` which I am sure is not what you desire. Pass `result` instead.

```
printf("%d", result);
```

When you wrote:

```
scanf("%c%*c", &c);
```

I presume that you in fact meant:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

Comment: if I change the code to printf("%d", result); I wil get:              printf("%d", result);                                       and if i change the code to scanf("%c", &c); %c will get white space from the first scanf()!!! so i have to write it this way scanf("%c%*c", &c); or this way scanf(" %c", &c);. it seems that %c in contrast to %d or %f does not skip white space.

Comment: I don't want to enter into a debugging exercise where I help you take your program to completion. You asked about `result` and I answered that.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
scanf("%c%*c", &c);
```

Change it to:

```
scanf("%c", &c);
```

And you have:

```
printf("%d", &result);
```

Change it to:

```
printf("%d", result);
```

Comment: Using `printf("%d", &result);` will always produce something strange!

Comment: @bash.d It is not strange. It is the address of the `result` varialbe in memory.

Comment: Yes, I know, it is just when you are expecting 10 or 3, and get 342643894 instead! I was just emphasizing...

Answer (score 0):

`result` value actually contains garbage value when it is not initialized properly. Hence, garbage in - garbage out!

Also this ->`printf("%d", &result);` should be `printf("%d",result);`

Comment: how should i initialize it properly??

Comment: @user2111549 However you like. At the moment you don't initialize it at all in some cases. I explained this in the first paragraph of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

initialize result and change printf("%d", &result); to printf("%d", result);